# Ajax request inside setInterval. Abort it and start again

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, setinterval

I'm doing `ajax` request(inside setInterval) inside another `ajax` , but I have to abort inner ajax after every tick and send it again every interval of time. Why I need `setInterval`? Because I have to check for an answer from server every second(user should call to number to activate feature). Why I need to `abort` request? Because while when I'm sending requests to server I can't go to another page/update page/ click to another another button to generate new number where to call(Actually I can, but if ajax isn't aborted it will wait until timeout), but it should be possible.

Question:
How to give an opportunity to leave page, click to another button, maybe do abort(but on new time interval continue send requests)?
[image]
On the image you can see that I got `console log` 20 times and `ajax` haven't been sent. (aborted at the end)

Looking for your advices, feel free to ask enything you need for better understanding

jQuery:

```
var ctimer;
var reply_wait;
var mpay_url = php.ajaxurl;
var ajax_reply;
var ajax_reply2;

/* Payment Start Listener */
jQuery(".mobile_pay_action").click(function () {

    clearInterval(ctimer);
    clearInterval(reply_wait);

    var m_pay_container = jQuery(this).data('container');
    var m_pay_case = jQuery(this).data('articleId');
    var static_id = jQuery(this).data('staticId');

    jQuery(m_pay_container).show();

    var pay = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: mpay_url,
        data: {
            artid: m_pay_case,
            action: 'mobile_pay_ajax',
            action2: 'pay'
        },
        success: function (r) {
            var d = JSON.parse(r);
            // console.log(d);
            jQuery('#mobile_pay').html(d.msg);
            if (d.status === "pay_wait") {

                ctimer = setInterval(function () {
                    m_pay_countdown();
                }, 1000);


                reply_wait = setInterval(function () {


                    ajax_reply = jQuery.ajax({
                        url: mpay_url,
                        data: {
                            'action2': 'pay_reply',
                            action: 'mobile_pay_ajax',
                            'artid': m_pay_case,
                            'static_article_id': static_id,
                            'm_pay_div': m_pay_container
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (typeof data.status !== 'undefined') {
                                if (data.status === "done") {
                                    clearInterval(ctimer);
                                    clearInterval(reply_wait);

                                    var expires = new Date();

                                    if(m_pay_case > 0 ){
                                        jQuery.cookie("newspaper_article_access_" + m_pay_case, m_pay_case, {
                                            expires : 30,
                                            path    : '/'
                                        });
                                    }else{
                                        expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24));
                                        jQuery.cookie("newspaper_one_day_access", 'access', {
                                            expires : expires,
                                            path    : '/'
                                        });
                                    }

                                    jQuery('.article_content_locker').hide();
                                    jQuery('.article.full_article .article_content').html(data.content);

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });


                    ajax_reply.abort();

                    console.log('request');

                }, 1000);

            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });

    return false;
});

function m_pay_countdown() {
    var sec = parseInt(jQuery('#m_pay_counter').text()) || 0;
    jQuery('#m_pay_counter').text(--sec);
    if (sec == 0) {
        var text = '<div class="mobile_payment_content_box"><span class="time_out">Aeg sai otsa!</span></div>';
        jQuery('#mobile_pay').html(text);
        clearInterval(ctimer);
        clearInterval(reply_wait);
    }
}
```